# Getting an InvalidParameterException when using compareFaces on aws-sdk-js

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk-js, amazon-rekognition

When using the compare faces function of the aws-sdk with nodeJS we are sporadically seeing this error:

```
InvalidParameterException: Request has Invalid Parameters
 at Request.extractError (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:48:27)
 at Request.callListeners (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
 at Request.emit (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
 at Request.emit (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
 at Request.transition (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)     at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
 at /app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
 at Request.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
 at Request.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
 at Request.callListeners (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
 at Request.emit (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
 at Request.emit (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)     at Request.transition (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
 at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
 at /app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
 at Request.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
   message: 'Request has Invalid Parameters',
   code: 'InvalidParameterException',
   time: 2018-05-08T15:27:28.188Z,
   requestId: 'XXXXX',
   statusCode: 400,
   retryable: false,
   retryDelay: 52.72405778418885 }
```

The images are captured every time using an iPhone camera, are saved as JPEG's and do contain faces. The images are not corrupt and have been tested using jpeginfo. They are then converted to binary and send to rekognition via the sdk. We have ran the same images through the python library Boto and successfully receive a comparison result.

Are there an further diagnostic steps we can take on the node side to aid in debugging? Or any insight into the cause of the error?

**Update:**

Image sizes: 
source: 1189 × 750
target: 360 × 480

Answer (score 0):

one thing you can do is, instead of directly calling Rekognition api through your javascript code , upload your image to s3 and make this upload a trigger to lambda function written in python , the lambda function will contain the comparision code and then store response in dynamodb table as a buffer place , then fetch data from dynamodb and use it as you want.

it looks a lengthy procedure but trust me I am using it too , and it's quite simple and gives us the advantage that processing is done in backend away from naive user.

here is the example of comparision code :
    import boto3
    import io
    from PIL import Image

```
rekognition = boto3.client('rekognition', region_name='eu-west-1')
dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='eu-west-1')

image = Image.open("group1.jpeg")
stream = io.BytesIO()
image.save(stream,format="JPEG")
image_binary = stream.getvalue()


response = rekognition.search_faces_by_image(
        CollectionId='family_collection',
        Image={'Bytes':image_binary}                                       
        )

for match in response['FaceMatches']:
    print (match['Face']['FaceId'],match['Face']['Confidence'])

    face = dynamodb.get_item(
        TableName='family_collection',  
        Key={'RekognitionId': {'S': match['Face']['FaceId']}}
        )

    if 'Item' in face:
       print (face['Item']['FullName']['S'])
    else:
       print ('no match found in person lookup')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but we are trying to avoid uploading the images to an s3 bucket for the comparison. We should be able to upload the images and compare but for some reason certain images are failing on the js sdk but getting a comparison in the python sdk.